# Define a parent method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

## I have 2 components:

### Modal component

- This component simply displays his `slot content`.
- In this modal I have two methods `submit` and `cancel`.

### ContractForm Component

- This is a simple component who displays a form.

### What I want ?

In my `ContractForm component`, I want to define the `submit` method of `Modal component`, this method must fetch the formdata of `ContractForm component`.

## My code

```
  <modal>
    <contract-form></contract-form>
  </modal>
```

Have you an idea how can I do this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to handle this.

### Method 1: `$emit` an event

The typical data flow structure in Vue.js is parents pass props down, and children emit events up.

In your case your parent is the `modal` and it has no props to pass so all you need to worry about is emitting a event from your child `contact-form` and listening for that event on the parent.

In your modal you have the methods submit and cancel so you could define your template like this.

```
<template>
    <contact-form @submit="submit" @cancel="cancel"/>
</template>
```

Then in your contact form component something like

```
<template>
  <div id="the-form">  
    <input type="text" v-model="formData.name">
    <input type="text" v-model="formData.email">.
 
    <button @submit="submitData">Submit</button>
    <button @canel="cancel">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>    
   ...
    data(){
        return {
           formData: {}
         }
    },
    methods:{
      submitData(){
           this.$emit('submit',this.formData);
      },
      cancel(){
         this.$emit('cancel');
      }

    }
```

In your modal components methods you simply get the values that are passed from the `@submit` and then do what ever you need with them.

```
methods:{
   submit(data){
       console.log(data); //do something with the emitted data
   }
}
```

Note that you can also often simply emit directly from the button @click definition without adding extra methods as long as you don't need to process the data or something of the sort.

```
<button  @click="$emit('submit',formData)">Submit</button>
<button @click="$emit('cancel)">Cancel</button>
```

---

### Method 2: Use the `$parent` "reference"

In this basic case you could simply reference your parent in your child and save a lot of work.

In your contact-form methods just reference your parent's  `submit()` and `cancel()` methods.

```
 methods:{
  submitData(){
       this.$parent.submit(this.formData);
  },
  cancel(){
     this.$parent.cancel();
  }

}
```

Or even more simply, as above with buttons, just do...

```
<button  @click="$parent('submit',formData)">Submit</button>
<button @click="$parent('cancel)">Cancel</button>
```

---

### Edit

After further discussion you indicated to want to reverse this having the child tell the parent what to do.

In that case you can still use something like the second method.  You can add a `ref` to your child component and then ref that child's methods through that ref.

So whenever you put a child in your modal you would do something like this.

```
 <the-child-component ref="modalContent"></the-child-component>
```

Then in your modal you would reference your child methods like this.

```
submit(){
    this.$refs.modalContent.submit();
},
```

See a working example here > https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/3bwpafr1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Your solution seems to me good.
`The problem` is that I want to have one modal component for my app.
Like this I need to define `submit method` of modal according to child component.
For exemple, one case I have a form into my modal component so the sumbit needs to fetch and another case I need to show an alert on `submit`. I swear you understand me.

Comment: I am not sure I understand.  So you want to actually define the actual method, what it does, in the child but use it in the parent?

Comment: Exactly! It is possible to do ? And how to do it ?

Comment: Ok I updated my answer above to show how you might do what you want.  See the Edit at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: The ref doesn't work because I use the ref in the `Form component` that is in `innerHtml` (slot) of my Modal component. So my $refs is empty. Can you help me ? Thanks

Comment: Bruno this has really become a different question, so I suggest you click the check box above to accept this answer, and then ask a new question giving the details of this new issue.  Then we can try to help you with it without making the answers here longer.